# how to make ros cpplint use a relative path for header guard check

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to force the ccpplint used by ros2 in ament to use a relative path starting at ros2_overylay_ws/src instead of the explicit full path when checking header guards?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285439/how-to-make-ros-cpplint-use-a-relative-path-for-header-guard-check/) by [dennis.bergin](https://answers.ros.org/users/34126/dennis.bergin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-03-14**:
Can you edit your question to also describe your folder layout exactly (maybe use the output of `tree`) and the exact command you're running and what folder it is in? Have you tried manually setting the `--root` option?

**Comment by [dennis.bergin](https://answers.ros.org/users/34126/dennis.bergin/) on 2018-03-17**:
I am using the command  ament test . I am not sure how to add the --root option.  A portion of my directory structure is as follows:
project location:  /home/dennis/Projects/ros2_overlay_ws/src/small_robot

within small_robot :
common/include
common/src
vms/contoller/include
vms/controller/src

**Comment by [dennis.bergin](https://answers.ros.org/users/34126/dennis.bergin/) on 2018-03-17**:
the cpplint mesage is as follows:
No #ifndef header guard found, suggested CPP variable is: _*HOME__DENNIS__PROJECTS__ROS2_OVERLAY_WS__SRC__SMALL_ROBOT__VMS__COMMON__INCLUDE__VMS_COMMON__ATTRIBUTE_HPP*  [build/header_guard] [5]

**Comment by [dennis.bergin](https://answers.ros.org/users/34126/dennis.bergin/) on 2018-03-17**:
The header guard for his file is #ifndef _*SMALL_ROBOT__VMS__COMMON__ATTRIBUTE_HPP*
I do not want to include the user specifc path portio "/home/dennis/projects/ros2_overlay_ws/src"

**Comment by [dennis.bergin](https://answers.ros.org/users/34126/dennis.bergin/) on 2018-03-17**:
lastly, sorry if my explanatio is confusing.  I showed two example directory structures.  the directory structure for the specific error message I provided is
small_robot/vms/common/attribute.h within /home/dennis/Projects/ros2_overlay_ws/src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `ament_cpplint` has two ways to detect the root for your source code:

1. It determines the `--root` by looking for known names in the path hierarchy, namely `include`, `src`, `test`. If you are using the latest release of ROS 2 (Ardent) this will likely not work for you. There was recently a fix for this logic (see https://github.com/ament/ament_lint/pull/94). You might want to consider to use a newer version of this package from source to make this work for your use case.
2. It also looks for the root of a git repository in case your code is using that. I guess that is not the case for you though.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dennis.bergin](https://answers.ros.org/users/34126/dennis.bergin/) on 2018-03-24**:
Thank you for the information. I updated my version of ament.  The problem has been alleviated.